# c# windows forms logout

Tags: sql-server, logout

How do you make a logout button in c# windows forms which closes a mssql connection.

I have a login form that sends username and password from one form to another. The connection string on form2 is placed under public partial class and looks like this:

```
public static
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
SqlCommand mySqlCmd = con.CreateCommand();
```

I've created a logout button on form2 which goes back to the first login form, but it doesn't seem to close the sqlconnection. You can just press the login button again without entering user and password and your through to form2 again.

So the first time you have to enter username and password and the second time you dont need to.

The code I use for the logout button is:

```
con.Close();
this.Close();
Form fmlogind = new logind();
fmlogind.Show();
```

Here is the whole code on the second form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


            public static
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
            SqlCommand mySqlCmd = con.CreateCommand();





        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text ="EasyAud";

        }


        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      

            easyAudToolStripMenuItem.Text = globalvariables.user;

            comboBox4.Items.Add("1");
            comboBox4.Items.Add("2");

            mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct firma from app";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (firmaReader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["firma"]);
            }

            firmaReader.Close();
            con.Close();

            mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct type from app";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader typeReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (typeReader.Read())
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(typeReader["type"]);
            }

            typeReader.Close();
            con.Close();


        }



        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox3.Items.Clear();



            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {


                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where type = '" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where type = '" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {


                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where farve = '" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where farve = '" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();

            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();

            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();



            }


            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {


                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where type = '" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where type = '" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();



            }
        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();



            }

            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {


                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where type = '" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where type = '" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {


                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where farve = '" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where farve = '" + farve + "'";               
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();

            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text == "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and type ='" + type + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }

            if (comboBox1.Text != "" && comboBox2.Text == "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {

                string firma = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where firma = '" + firma + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";               
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();


            }


            if (comboBox1.Text == "" && comboBox2.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
            {


                string type = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string farve = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct ha from app where type = '" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader firmaReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (firmaReader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(firmaReader["ha"]);
                }

                firmaReader.Close();
                con.Close();


                mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where type = '" + type + "' and farve ='" + farve + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (farveReader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
                }

                farveReader.Close();
                con.Close();

            }

        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            string ha = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select distinct farve from app where ha = '" + ha + "'";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader farveReader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (farveReader.Read())
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(farveReader["farve"]);
            }

            farveReader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox4.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (comboBox4.Text == "" || comboBox3.Text == "" || listBox1.Text == "")
            {

                MessageBox.Show("HA-Valg blev ikke gemt!" + "\n" + "Felterne: antal, ha og farve skal udfyldes", "Ikke gemt");
            }


            if (comboBox4.Text != "" && listBox1.Text != "")
            {
                string ha = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Clipboard.SetText(comboBox4.Text + "stk " + ha + " i farve " + comboBox3.Text);
            }
        }

        private void logAfToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Close();
            Form fmlogind = new logind();
            fmlogind.Show();


        }

        private void easyAudToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lukToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }









    }
}
```

Comment: This behavior should have *nothing* to do with closing the SQL connection.  Database connections should be opened, used, and closed within a very small scope only when they're needed.  If your application is leaving connections open then that's a resource leak and needs to be fixed.  In any event, whether or not a database connection is open shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not a user is authenticated.  It sounds like your authentication mechanism (which you're not showing) isn't working.  (Also, having a single static `Connection` object is a *famously* bad idea.)

Comment: right now there is no authentication mechanism. If you type in a username and password that has access to the mssql table your in, else an error shows.

Comment: If there's no authentication mechanism then what do you expect is going to stop the (mis-named) login button from opening the form?

Comment: I thought that if the entered username and password doesn't have access to the database that would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code executes *once* and *only once* no matter how many times you open the form:

```
public static
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
```

Aside from the use of global variables (bad idea) and the use of a single static database connection (bad idea), once you've created that connection the first time it will *always* exist as a `static` property on that type.

From that point forward, you can enter all the username and password values you like.  You may be updating the global variables associated with them, but you're *not* updating the `con` variable.  The right-hand side of that expression doesn't hold a *reference* to those global variables to be evaluated multiple times, it just evaluates them *once* and keeps the result of that evaluation.

So your order of events in this case is:

1. Create the connection using the supplied username and password.
2. Open the connection.
3. Use the form, connection, etc.
4. Close the connection.
5. Change the username and password variables, but not the connection.
6. Re-open the *original* connection, using the *original* connection string.

Your best approach for fixing this is to remove the `SqlConnection` object from `static` scope.  If you want to try to initiate a database connection when the form loads, do it in the constructor or in the `Form1_Load` event handler.  And instead of re-using the same always-open connection throughout the application, any time you need to access the database you should create a connection local to that scope and dispose of it as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: I've just moved the sqlconnection from public static inside all of the if statements and it works, thanks!!

Comment: @user3888775: This has been explained many times over many years in much more detail and eloquence than I can provide.  For example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: Do you know how to make an sql query with multiple where clauses, where the number of where clauses are user-defined like "Select * from something where (if isset size = userinput) and (if isset color = userinput ) and ....... Then I would be able to get rid of all the if statements.

Comment: @user3888775: Your first step should be to use parameterized queries instead of directly concatenating user input to your SQL code.  What you're currently doing opens the application to SQL injection attacks.  As for conditionally building a SQL query, you can create a SQL string and then add more strings to it (ideally using a `StringBuilder`) in `if` blocks.

Comment: Do you know where i can read more about building these kind of queries?